# cannot plot with matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using OSX (Mojave 10.14.3) and am having a strange issue plotting a `pandas (0.24.2)` dataframe using `matplotlib (3.0.3)`. I am using python `3.7.3`.

So, the code is as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
                  'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
                  'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
                  'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
                  'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
                  'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
                  })

df.plot(kind='scatter',x='num_children',y='num_pets',color='red')
plt.show()
```

All this does is show an empty window with nothing in it. I was expecting a scatterplot with 7 points. The example is taken from the web tutorial as is.

**EDIT**

```
plt.savefig('myfilename.png')
```

Savefig works.

Comment: Your code works on my computer, with pandas version '0.21.1' and matplotlib version 2.2.0. What versions do you have?

Comment: I updated the question with the versions. Are you using a mac as well?

Comment: Are you using a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Do other plots work (`plt.plot(range(10))`; plt.show()`?)  If not, they you likely have a backend problem; do you get any errors?  My guess would be your install is crossed somehow.

Comment: @araraonline No, just running it with a script.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Ok, that does not work either. I am using anaconda and have installed matplotlib through anaconda as well....

Comment: Someone reported a similar problem yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013105/matplotlib-plot-window-is-white-blank-without-showing-any-image

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help anyone but I basically had to install python as a framework to make it work. I was using `Anaconda`, so something like:

```
conda install python.app
pythonw script.py  # note using pythonw
```

I, then, was able to get the plot to render correctly by using the `macosx` backend:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('MacOSX')
```

Comment: Right you can’t run macosx backend w/o using pythonw for now.  As of 3.1 you should be able to.  However it’s strange that you got a blank figure.  Were there any warnings?

Comment: @JodyKlymak No warnings. My default backend was TkAgg and I still get a blank figure with that for some reason...

Comment: Ok I don’t think anaconda installs tk by default so it was probably trying to use the system to libraries?  If you specifically install tk in conda does it work?